# Supermicro server motherboard X10QBi (Rev. 1.01A) post code 15 issue

Tags: memory, motherboard, xeon, supermicro

I've bought off eBay a super micro CSE-848X chassis complete with a Mainboard: X10QBi (Rev. 1.01A) and 8 X10QBi-MEM1 Memory Cards and it will not boot...

It is stuck at "system initializing" and postcode 15 from what I could tell from searching the web its related to memory problems or CPU pins...

I've bought a bundle of different ddr3 ECC reg rams and I've tried different combinations of rams and none work.
It supports up to 4 CPU's I have 4 and currently, it has installed 2 Intel Xeon E7-4890 v2 and four 8GB DIMMs ECC reg 2RX4 PC3-10600R in correct DIMM slot 2 per memory card per CPU...

Question 1# Can I run this board with only 2 CPU's installed?

Question 2# Can I run with only one DIMM per CPU? since the manufacturer recommends running system with full DIMM slot occupied or half slots occupied...

What could I try to change to make it post?
It turns on and outputs image but I can't get it to pass the message "system initializing" and postcode 15... could it be that none of the rams I have is compatible with this system?

Comment: As long as the modules are equivalent to a module that is specifically supported you are fine.  Is that the case?  What is more likely is the motherboard is just not functional.  "Pre-memory North Bridge initialization is started" is entirely CPU which likely means the socket.

Comment: Maybe that's why it was for sale.

Comment: but I'm wondering if I could in a working motherboard of the same model, boot with just one DIMM and one CPU can someone answer this? it would facilitate much of the testing I need to do